# how to put a link inside of fancybox?

Tags: hyperlink, fancybox, lightbox

Sorry I don't know much (anything) of js and  I am working with fancybox version 2 for a website I am doing.

The problem is that I need to put these two text-links inside of the lightbox, under the photo.

Details

View on Flickr

But I don't know how and where I need to put them! =S
If someone could help me please!

Thx, =D

Answer (score -1):

It would be easier to create a new page with all the information on it (laid out as you choose), then link to that page using fancybox's iframe mode.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I got that page done.
It's the page where I am linking (Details and View on flickr), but not sure what you mean with the iframe. 
Can I write the <a href> somewhere in the title part of the script ?
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#photos a").fancybox({
    helpers: {
     title : {
      type : 'outside'
     },
     overlay : {
      speedIn : 400,
      opacity : 0.85
     }
    }
  
   });
  });

Comment: Update your question with a description of what you have and the code.